# How can add an "All Items" field to a jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am trying to make a Swing GUI in Netbeans. I create a jcombobox and I bind it (using a query component, a list component and a renderer) to an entity called 'Item', so that the combobox shows the names of the items that currently exist in the table "Item" and so far it works fine. However, I need to add an "All Items" field to the combobox. Does anybody have any hints on where I should start?

Comment: You'll need to extend `JComboBox` and define that method there.

Comment: You can initialize a JComboBox with an array http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/300492-how-to-add-an-object-array-into-a-jcombobox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    List<String> listItems = classDAO.findElement();

    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

    for(String string : listItems)
    {
        comboModel.addElement(string);
    }

    comboModel.addElement("All items");

    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add an item to the combo box after the items from the table have been added to the combo box:

```
comboBox.addItemAt("All Items", 0);
```

will insert a new item at the top of the combo box.

Comment: I added this, in the constructor, after the initComponents() call, however I get an exception "Cannot use this method with non-mutable Data Model".

Comment: @Sofia : how do you usually "give" the data o your comboboxes ?

Comment: @sofia, then you need to create a new DefautlComboBoxModel and copy each item from the exiting model to the new model. The basic approach has been shown by Gerry in that answer.

Comment: After I have inserted the combobox in the Design environment, I create an itemQuery and a query result list, create the apropriate itemRenderer and then set the combobox's renderer to itemRenderer. So the initComponents() method's code is generated and can't modify it manually.

Comment: @Sofia, I don't use an IDE so I don't know the steps involved to add custom code. This is why I always recommend to NOT use an IDE because you spend time learning the IDE and not learning Java/Swing. Also, the code you generate will not be portable if you move to another IDE.

Comment: I totally agree with you, unfortunately it is a school project and have to do it using an IDE..

Comment: @Sofia, Then ask your friends or teaches how to use the IDE to customize the code. This should be something basic you learn in class.